# Es war einmal vs Eines Tages

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-order

Wäre es richtig, wenn man schreibt:

***Es war einmal*** eine Witwe, die Irma hieß. ***Eines Tages*** war sie im Wald (...)

Kann man **es war einmal** anwenden und dann im nächsten Satz **eines Tages** an den Anfang stellen?

Ist das idiomatisch und grammatikalisch richtig?

Comment: Das geht problemlos

Comment: "Ich esse gerne Äpfel. Morgen kaufe ich Birnen." - ja, man kann diese 2 Sätze hintereinander verwenden und Birnen kaufen, wenn man gerne Äpfel isst.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selbstverständlich, das widerspricht sich nicht. Ob sich »eines Tages« auf die Vergangenheit oder auf die Zukunft bezieht, muss aus dem Kontext hervorgehen. In deinem Fall ist es die Vergangenheit.

Beispiel für die Zukunft:

> Eines Tages wirst auch du heiraten.